# Is energy applied by the muscle when it holds a body in the air?

Tags: energy, biophysics, work

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does holding something up cost energy while no work is being done?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1984/why-does-holding-something-up-cost-energy-while-no-work-is-being-done)

We all know the following Newtonian formulas:

PotentialGravitationEnergy=m*g*h 
Kinetic Energy = 0.5m * v^2 
W = F * distance 
Therefore, if I put an apple on a table, it will not gain nor lose [potential] energy - because F = 0, and distance = 0.

But when I'm not using a 'mechanic lock' like that - but using my body muscle [without locking the bone] to hold the apple in the air - I'm damn right applying energy - my muscle is getting warmer [because glucose burning is very inefficient] - and I feel it stretching.

I DO apply a force towards up - but it's not a 'free force' like the Normal force - but I give no energy to the apple.

Can anyone please explain to me in detail what is actually happening? Thank you very much!

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1984/2451

Comment: glucose burning is inefficient but not "very" inefficient!!

Comment: a physics "work" is different from a normal day usage "work"... the definitions are different.

Comment: Vineet - I do understand the difference. But still - why is my muscle heating up and getting harder?