# Why is work not related to velocity?

Tags: energy, velocity, work, biophysics

A very simple question; why does it cost me more energy to **very slowly** lift a mass $m$ over my head compared to very fast? The definition of work does not state anything about velocity, only the distance travelled, but I definitely feel more exhausted in the first case.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1984/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same reason why simply holding the mass over your head uses energy, even though the mass is not moving.  And the reason is the way your muscle tissue works, which is to continually contract and then relax - obviously with different parts of the same muscle firing off at different times.