# Force times Displacement conserves itself

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Was it decided **empirically** (in order to respect the already found Conservation of Energy's law) that force x displacement is the quantity that corresponds to the energy ?

It's a deeper question than it looks, at least for me :)

Comment: Perhaps you would get a better answer on History of Science.SE?

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128598/how-was-the-definition-and-the-formula-of-work-derived-is-it-the-best-possible Maybe some answers herein can help