# What is happening to energy that is not used as work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

To my understanding (which is pretty basic), energy is the ability to do work. But if for example, I push a wall, I do exhaust my energy, but no work is done since the wall is not moving. So what is happening to the energy? Thanks.

Comment: My English is not so good, so if someone could fix bad English in the question I would be grateful.

Comment: See also [The physical definition of work seems paradoxical](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127326/the-physical-definition-of-work-seems-paradoxical)

Comment: @JohnRennie After reading the answer to the original question, I think I understand. There is not much energy spend, and the energy that I do spend is converted to other types of energy such as heat or voice. Am I correct?

Comment: Suppose you apply a force to the wall be leaning some heavy object against it. There is a force on the wall, but no work is being done. However unlike the heavy object your muscles need to consume energy to maintain a constant force, which is just down to the way muscles operate. The energy consumed by your muscles ends up as heat.