# Does gravity (and all other fundamental forces, for that matter) have infinite energy as they seemingly last forever?

Tags: gravity, forces, energy

If I put a brick *onto an steel platform*, that *platform can hold the brick* *A LONG TIME, if not FOREVER.* **Does the platform exert force?** *If so*, then **shouldn't it have infinite energy to resist the pull of gravity?** *If not*, **shouldn't it hold at least an ENORMOUS amount of energy** to support the brick? *And if* the platform **does NOT exert energy**, then **what is holding the brick back from plummeting to the earth?**

*Thanks guys! :)*

EDIT: Come to think of it, the platform is held together by the electromagnetic force. But I still wonder whether or not gravity and the other fundamental forces have infinite energy or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does holding something up cost energy while no work is being done?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1984/)

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177643/

Answer (score 0):

Energy is only expended in movement. In a stationary configuration (holding a brick), energy is not expended. The brick is held back by a static force, which requires no input to maintain itself and expends no resources in doing so.

Comment: So... a force that requires no energy yet resists energy inputted against it? @zeldredge

Comment: There is no energy input against it. Work is only done by a force if the object the force is on moves. A stationary object, even when subjected to forces, has no work done on it. Its energy does not change. Therefore no energy is spent by the external force.

Comment: How about gravity? It moves objects. Does it expend energy? @zeldredge

Comment: Yes. When it moves objects. When an object is sitting at rest on a shelf, it does not expend energy. When two objects move towards each other, the gravitation potential energy in the system composed of those objects is reduced.