# Change of energy into friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, biophysics, dissipation

If I am pushing a car and it does not move, I am doing no mechanical work. However, I am  changing the energy that was stored in my cells into heat energy (maybe sound energy if my hand slips off the car). So does this lost heat energy transfer into the surface of the car where I am touching it or into the frictional land which is in contact with the tyres of the car?

Comment: Only to the extent that the car is moving microscopically. All the rest is merely making you sweat because your body has to get rid of the excess heat that is being generated by your muscles.

Comment: See also: [Why does holding something up cost energy while no work is being done?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1984/)

Comment: You're asking where the heat energy goes.  Ultimately it gets distributed into everything comprising the surroundings, including the air, the ground, your car, and everything else.

Answer (score -1):

the work which friction between car and surface do is zero;as distance is zero(w=fdcosx)
but where your energy go?
in fact your friends know.
when you push the car you heat yourself and you sweat.
so every one know where energy has gone.**you smell bad man.**