# How to calculate the work without displacement?

Tags: energy, newtonian-gravity, work, biophysics, elasticity

For example, I hold an item in my hand at arm's length. There are forces of gravity and elasticity. And obviously I use some amount of energy to keep holding. Is it possible to calculate the work without displacement?
I've finished high school years ago, it's just my curiosity.

Comment: If there is no displacement, there is no work (in the physicist's sense) made by any force applied. This  is unrelated with the energy you might or might not need to generate a given force in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1984/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no displacement, there's no work done. Work without displacement is zero.

The force of gravity pulls down on the item, you are holding. But in general, no, you *do not* spend energy to keep it up.

- If the item is on a shelf, this shelf is *not* continuously spending energy to keep it up. It spends *no* energy and does *do* work.
- When you hold the item still in a certain height, that's the same situation. No work is done on the item.

**But** your body is a strange thing and always tricky to see in this context. Because of muscle expansion and compression and other processes within your body, your body spends energy of many reasons in order to create the force that holds up the item. Work is done internally on that, but no work done *on the item*.

Answer (score 1):

No work is done without displacement. Why holding up an object still costs the body energy see: [Why does holding something up cost energy while no work is being done?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1984/why-does-holding-something-up-cost-energy-while-no-work-is-being-done)

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that there is work done on the item due to small oscillations caused by the body and the body trying to compensate for them