# When we push a wall, we get tired Why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, biology

When we push a wall the wall does not move so, no work is done but still we get tired Why? What energy changes occur in this process.

Comment: Do you get tired when you lean on a wall? Because that is also pushing on it ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does holding something up cost energy while no work is being done?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1984/)