# Why we don't work physically when we don't make something move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, biophysics

The formula for Work is F*x, where x is distance taken. So by physicially work formula, why don't we experience any work if we do not make any object move? Is there a specific reason?

Example, I am pushing a table with 10 N and distance travelled is $1m$, thus $W = 10 N*m$. But when table travels $0$ metres, by the formula $W = F*0$ and thus $W=0$; means that we didn't do any work.

So why is that? At the end of the day we did apply force to table?

Comment: Not only has it been asked before, it’s MANY times before  on this site. The short answer is physical effort does not always equal physics work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does holding something up cost energy while no work is being done?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1984/)

Comment: Or ask your question with more details explaining why your question is different or why the previous answers didn’t resolve your questions

Comment: I see, thank you