# If two opposing equal forces act on an object, how does one calculate the energy exerted?

Tags: forces, energy, distance

If energy exerted is a function of distance and force, the object would not move in this case. But would energy not still be exerted?

Simplified the example for sake of clarity; but specifically asking with regards to a person doing something like a bicep curl and learning to only squeeze their bicep, rather than tensing their whole arm and fighting against themselves.

Comment: I do not think that biomechanics is within the remit of this Physics Stack Exchange.  It is more of a Biology (or Engineering) question.

Comment: From a pure physics standpoint, work requires displacement.

Comment: Related:  [Why does holding something up cost energy while no work is being done?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1984/why-does-holding-something-up-cost-energy-while-no-work-is-being-done), which explains the difference between physics work and biomechanical energy expenditure.  I agree with farcher that calculating the latter is difficult and that you're unlikely to get an answer for it here.